# Check if a list is empty (Raku)

Tags: raku

FAQ: In Raku how to check if a list is empty ?
Are there more idiomatic ways than:

```
my @l = ();
say @l.elems == 0;
say @l == ();
say @l.Bool;
```

The [doc on list](https://docs.perl6.org/type/List) recommends [smartmatching](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_~~)

```
say $l ~~ ();
```

1. Do you know other ways ?
2. Can you explain why  `() === ()` is wrong even if `"" === ""` is right: I'm not clear on that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of those suggested:

```
say @l.elems == 0;
```

This is a good one to avoid, because it forces evaluation of all elements in a lazy list (which may lead to an exception if there are iterators marked as lazy, since the alternative would be running until all memory is exhausted).

```
say @l == ();
```

This works, but has the same problem as above. The `==` operator is numeric equality, and so it will coerce both sides to a number and then compare them. That also boils down to `@l.elems` (via. `@l.Numeric`). You could write this form cheaper as `@l == 0`, which is the neatest way if you really do want to ask for how many elements there are in total.

```
say @l.Bool;
```

This is better, because in a lazy list it only forces evaluation of one element at most to answer the question. However, it's actually the inverse of what was asked: this is `True` if the array is *not* empty. It's more natural to use the `?` and `!` prefix operators like this:

```
say ?@l; # is not empty
say !@l; # is empty
```

Though often you don't even need to do *that*, because things like `if` and `unless` provide a boolean context. Thus one could write:

```
if @l { }        # not empty
unless @l { }    # empty
```

These are probably the best ways.

As to other suggestions:

```
say $l ~~ ();
```

This is fine, though probably slower than the boolification approach.

> `() === ()` is wrong even if `"" === ""` is right

That's because `List` is a reference type, not a value type. Since `()` constructs a distinct empty list each time, they are distinct objects, and so will compare as non-identical. You can use `eqv` instead:

```
say () eqv ()    # True
```

But don't use this to check if a list is empty, because it's probably overly specific. For example:

```
my @l; say @l eqv ();    # False
my @l; say @l eqv [];    # True
```

This is because `()` is of type `List`, while `my @l` declares an `Array`. In general, you don't want to care what type is really there.

Finally, about this line:

```
my @l = ();
```

The assignment of `()` is pointless; `my @a` already creates an empty `Array`. In fact, it's a common enough code smell that Comma IDE gives a weak warning about this:

[image: Warning]

Comment: Let's not forget about "@a ~~ Empty", which also seems to work with an `==` although that's probably because both coerce numerically to 0.