# Are there cases when I have to use `elems` with an array to make it work?

Tags: arrays, element, raku

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60858379/198183) I looked through my code and found some places where I use `elems` with arrays.

I could remove all `elems` without affecting the code:

```
my @a = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
my $b = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];

my $i = 2;
say $i + @a.elems;
say $i + @a;

say "===============";
say @a.elems;
say 0 + @a;

say "===============";
say $b.elems / 2;
say $b / 2;

say "===============";
while state $c++ > $b.elems {
    say $c;
}
while state $d++ > $b {
    say $d;
}
```

That led me to wonder if there are situations where arrays have to be called with the `elems` function to make the code work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever a numeric operator sees an `Iterable` as one of its operands, it will call the `.elems` method on it.  Sometimes that will result in a `Failure` or an `Exception` being thrown:

```
$ raku -e 'say (1 ... *) + 42'
Cannot .elems a lazy list
```

Mind you, using the `.elems` in your code has 2 advantages:

- it makes your intention explicit, good for future maintainers
- it will be slightly more efficient, because it will skip the operator call